# SAML authentication on Android mobile app

Tags: android, authentication, android-webview, saml, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to integrate my android mobile app with SAML authentication service.

I created a webview and call the provider url.

My webview is redirected to the auth form and I fill it with user and password but after that my webview is redirected to a page showing me the following error message:

"Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared."

I can't understand how to solve the issue and complete the authentication using the webviews.

I can't find a good example of this authentication using webviews or chrome custom tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable session storage on the Android Mobile App.

See here on how to enable it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-enable-web-view-session-storage-in-android